# How can I detect the selectedSegmentIndex when long-pressing down?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uisegmentedcontrol

UILongPressGestureRecognizer got added to UISegmentedControl.
Is there a way to detect selectedSegmentIndex when long-pressing down?
thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try adding a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to it? In viewDidLoad:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
longPress.delegate = self;
[segmentedControl addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Don't forget to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to your header file.

To know where is pressed:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:segmentedControl];
}
```

Then you could check what segment of segmentedControl matches with CGPoint p, check for the Y-coordinate, for example. When it's left from the middle line of the UISegmentedControl it's segment 0, when it's right of that line it's segment 1.

Comment: And to remove it in the viewDidUnload

Comment: Thanks your comment. But I want to know  index value of the segment control when long-pressing down. longpressgesturerecognizer works well. My problem is not adding a gesture but checking a index value.

Comment: you mean the segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex value?

Comment: Hi @Mathijs.  When Longpressgesturerecognizer is added to UITableview,I could know the IndexPath value where long-pressing down using - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point . Like that, I want to know index value of segmentcontrol where long-pressing down.

Comment: Well, UISegmentedControl doesn't have those delegate methods that that a UITableView has. Maybe you can tweak around it by using the method in my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You register for long press in UISegmentedControl

```
  let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ListQuizViewController.segmentLongPress(_:)))
    //longPress.delegate = self;
    self.segmentedControl.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1
```

You get index of selected button as follows with the assumption that segments are **equally spaced**

```
 func segmentLongPress(gestureRecognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let p = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.segmentedControl)
        let index = Int(ceil( p.x/(self.segmentedControl.frame.width/4))) - 1
       self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = index

    }
```

Comment: this works well and I can detect long press on segmented control, but is there any way to prevent the segmented control's normal action if the touch ends up being a long press? ... ive got a utilities segmented control where one of the segments triggers a segue to a thumbnail view controller so I don't want to trigger that segue if the user is actually long pressing on that segment